# How to make a command appear as text

Tags: overleaf

I am needing to type the sentence:
or by changing the environment from \begin{align} to \begin{align*} there will be no tags.
Every time I try this, Latex thinks that I am trying to start a new environment. This is not the case. I am just wanting it written in a sentence. I have tried {\texttrm{\begin{align}} and a few others, but nothing is working. Please help.

Comment: yes. Thank you so much!!! I have been struggling with this for 30 minutes. I tried the verbatim command and it changed the font... just never saw this. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I am needing to type the sentence: or by changing the environment from \begin{verbatim}\begin{align*} to \begin{align*}\end{verbatim} there will be no tags. 

or

I am needing to type the sentence: or by changing the environment from \verb+\begin{align*} to \begin{align*}+ there will be no tags. 
  
  \end{document}
```

`+` after `\verb` is a character that will never appear in the text inside the `align` environment.

[image]